# Reusing try catch for wcf call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, .net-3.5

I have a series of methods that call wcf services and all of them have the same try catch code

```
Response Method1(Request request)
{
    Response response = null;
    using(ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myEndpoint))
    {
        IService1 channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            response = channel.Operation(request);
        }
        catch(CommunicationException ex)
        {
            // Handle Exception
        }
        catch(TimeoutException ex)
        {
            // Handle Exception
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle Exception
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

And so on (I have 6 methods like this for different services).. how can i encapsulate all the service calls and handle the exceptions in a single method

**EDIT**

Following Nathan A's advice I created a simple generic method:

```
protected TResult ExecuteAndCatch<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> serviceCall, T request)
    where T : Request
    where TResult : Response
{
    try
    {
        return serviceCall(request);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

The new methods would like this

```
Response NewMethod1(Request request)
{
    Response response = null;
    using(ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myEndpoint))
    {
        IService1 channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        response = channel.Operation(request);
    }
    return response;
}
```

and i'm trying to call it like

```
Response response = ExecuteAndCatch<Response>(NewMethod1, new Request())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And is it really a `client.Operation();` or more like a `var x = client.Function(y);`

Comment: it has a request and a response structure.. so yeah the 2nd :)

Comment: What _are_ you doing wrong? What problem are you getting now?

Comment: Just looking at your method definition, I see you are missing T as a type argument.  Should be `ExecuteAndCatch<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> serviceCall, T request)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wrapper function.

Take a look at this article: [http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog:writing-wcf-wrapper-and-catching-common-exceptions](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog%3awriting-wcf-wrapper-and-catching-common-exceptions)

Here's an example from the article:

```
private void ExecuteAndCatch<T> (Action<T> action, T t) {
    try {
        action (t);
        Success = true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException) {
        Success = false;
        Message = "Timeout exception raised.";
    }
    catch (CommunicationException) {
        Success = false;
        Message = "Communication exception raised.";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the idea. OP just lookout whether exceptions are actually dealt with in the same manner for all methods

Comment: I should use Func<T, TResult> instead of Action<T> since the method returns a value, right?

Comment: Ya, you can adjust it as much as you need.  I believe there is an example of a return value implementation in the article.

Answer (score 1):

If your client derives from  `ClientBase<T>` e.g `MyClient : ClientBase<IWCFService>`

You could then create your own base class that provides methods that will wrap the common functionality.

The below sample code could be expanded to allow the final derived class to specify what to do when a particular method call fails.  Here I just call `HandleError`

In specific client class

```
//method that returns a value
public int Ping()
{
    return Protect(c => c.Ping());
}    

//void method usage
public void Nothing(int stuff)
{
    Protect(c => c.Nothing(stuff));
}
```

In client base class

```
protected void Protect(Action<IWCFService> action)
{
    Protect(c => { action(c); return true; });
}

//add other exception handling
protected Protect<T>(Func<IWCFService, T> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func(Channel);
    }
    catch (FaultException e)
    {
        HandleError(e);//up to you to implement this and any others
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inject the various clients through an interface and then run the operation in a single place?

```
HttpResponse performOperation(IServiceClient injectedServiceClient)
{
    IServiceClient client = injectedServiceClient;

    try
    {
        client.Operation();
    }
    catch(CommunicationException ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
    catch(TimeoutException ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception
    }
    return httpResponse(httpStatusCode.OK);
}
```