# Catch and Log all Errors

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Is there a way to catch errors, log them and return. on a GLOBAL scale.

Similar to the global.asmx usage on an MVC application.

Currently I have to write this around every method, so that I can log the error before returning it. Its a bit tedious.

I just want to intercept any errors returned, and log them before they are returned.

```
try
{
     // My method's code
}
catch (Exception e)
 {
     LogHelper.e(e);
     throw e;
 }
```

Comment: WCF has very powerful (and complex) hooks to do a variety of things. Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you want a library/class responsible to log error?

Comment: @ManthanDavda No, specifically, how to catch errors on a global scale. I already have my own logging class. Thanks.

Comment: @Crowcoder That looks promising. Will give it a read. currently stuck on something else.

Comment: @Crowcoder Hey, i have tried this, but neither methods ever seem to be called.

Comment: I haven't used this myself, but I use other hooks into the pipeline. In my experience the problem is usually with your service model configuration. That is always a bear to figure out.

Comment: @Crowcoder Based on your recommendation of `IErrorHandler` I was able to [find another help guide by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751439(v=vs.110).aspx) with an example of attribute usage of it. The sample can be downloaded from them [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150780) and is found in the folder: `WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Extensibility\ErrorHandling\ErrorLogging\CS`. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, I may use that myself, thanks.

Comment: Have you see this other [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524280/reusing-try-catch-for-wcf-call) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do that but I'm sure **it's not recommended**.

See: [Exception Handling (c# Best practices)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx)

Comment: One of the provided examples is similar to what i do. Log the error then re-throw it. Whether its possible to do it on a global scale, i don't know. But I'm not convinced yet that it is not recommended. Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF here is an example of what you can do using Log4Net. I have built upon this example and implemented central logging for my WCF services using Application Insights.

[Logging All Unhandled Exceptions In Wcf Using Log4Net](https://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/logging-all-unhandled-exception-in-wcf-with-log4net/)